# With Angular UI Router, how do make a state a child of all states?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-router

I'd like to make modal dialog boxes into a separate state within Angular UI Router. However, I have a case where the modal box can/should appear on top of all states... and I am not sure if this is possible.

So for example, let's say I have `/store` and `/admin` as 2 separate top-level states. Now imagine that I have a modal dialog that is unrelated, like a contact form (just as an example) that should go on top of each.

If I model this as `/contact`, the `/store` or `/admin` states are obviously forgotten, so the background behind the modal is blank.

The solution might be to have two child states, like `/store/contact` and `/admin/contact`, and this preserves the content behind the modal dialog box... however, this approach does not scale for X number of top-level states.

In a nutshell, how can I say that `/contact` is a child of all states, regardless of nesting? Is this possible? Or do I simply have to not use angular UI router in this case?

Comment: Radim's answer (iterate over each state programmatically and add a substate) is definitely a pattern I promote.  Also, check out UI-Router Extras "Sticky States".  There's an example which provides a solution to the state layout you have proposed with a modal state "on the side": http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/stickymodal/#/

Answer (score 0):

The `UI-Router` state machine is expressed with *parent-child* relations. So the answer is - *each child can have just/exactly **one** Parent*. That's a fact. And it could be treated as *"kind of not working answer"*.

But, in case that we really would like to have many child states `/contact` `(where` contact `feature is moved to its own state)`, I would **not** say that repeating of definition is an issue.

It could be marked as overhead, but state is just a **configuration**. It does not affect the performance so much. The *views* and *controllers* are instantiated per state anyhow... regardless of its state def.

```
// declare once view
var contactState = {
  controller: ...
  template: ...
  ...
};

// reuse as need for some ...
stateNamesWithContact.forEach( function(stateName)
{
    // regiester state many times as "some.parnet.child.contact"
    $stateProvider
        .state(stateName + ".contact", contact);
    ...
```

Another approach, which I would perfer, is to **NOT** use `Contact` as a substate. Move it into view *(which functionality will support modals)*

#### [Multiple Named Views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

**Defined once, in root state - as a view**

In case, that **Contact** view/controller are static, we can just hook them into supper root state:

```
.state("root", {
    views : {        
        "" : {
           template: "<ui-view />" // here will be injected all children
        }
        "contact@" : {
           ... //setting of the Contact view / controller
        }
    }
}
```

Now, each "parent" state can profit from the above, without having affected `url` or `name` *(no need to have "root.someParent" if `parent` setting is used)*

```
.state("someState", {
    parent: "root"
    ...
```